# Remove "?" from the query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

I have decided to ditch Wordpress and move to [Pico CMS](http://picocms.org/) instead.

Now I'm struggling with getting the URL rewriting done correctly.

I have managed to rewrite the query string from eg. `https://www.example.org?page` to `https://www.example.org/page` using `RewriteRule ^(.*) ?$1 [L]`, but now I also want it rewritten if there **is** a query string.

Example:

If `https://www.example.org?page` is requested it loads just fine, but I want to have it rewritten as `https://www.example.org/page` - at least in the location bar.

I have tried several variations but to no avail. I suck at regular expressions...

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^\\?/(.*)$ $1`

Nope

`RewriteRule (^\?$) https://tanghus.net/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://tanghus.net/? [NC,R=301,L]`

no dice

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ %{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]`

Pfff

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`

Giving up :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Rule

```
RewriteEngine on

# externally  redirect from /?page to /page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [L,R]
# internally map /page to /?page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /?$1 [L]
```

Comment: That absolutely did the trick! Thanks a lot. I really should have paid more attention to RegExps 20+ years ago ;)